# How to fix Update error for The POST method is not supported for this route in Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to laravel I'm trying to create an Todo App for a simple CRUD project but I got an Error that said

> The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, DELETE.

I've been searching for the solution and try them all but somehow the solution does not fix my error.

`web.php`

```
Route::get('/', 'TaskController@index');
Route::resource('task','TaskController');
```

`TaskController`

```
   public function edit(Task $task)
    {
        return view('task.edit')->with('task', $task);
    }

    public function update(Request $request, Task $task)
    {
        $task->update($request->all());
        return redirect('/');
    }
```

`edit.blade.php`

```
 <form action="{{route('task.update', $task->id)}}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        method('PATCH')
        <div class="input-group mb-3 w-100">
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="title" value="{{$task->title}}" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="button-addon2">
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="button-addon2">Update</button>
            <div>
        <div>
        </form>
```

Route List:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update operations is traditionally done with `PUT` or `PATCH` calls. Form does not support this, but `Laravel` supports doing an hidden input field with the name `_method`, that indicate if it should be a `PUT`.

Your syntax is not correct and should be.

```
<form action="{{route('task.update', $task->id)}}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    @method('PATCH')
```